# Using Excel file as mapping for pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I'm trying to use an excel "master list" of error codes and the larger group in which they belong to group errors by the larger group in a pandas data frame. I'm unsure of how to do this. I previously tried adding the error codes to a dictionary with the group name as they key and grouping by that, but it wouldn't properly group the codes. I'll add examples of my master list and data frame below.

Master list:

| CODE | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3 | Type4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Code A |  | X |  |  |
| Code B | X |  |  |  |
| Code C | X |  |  |  |
| Code D |  |  |  | X |
| Code E |  |  | X |  |

and so on for 10 columns and 57 rows

DataFrame:

| CODE | Numerator | Denominator | Error Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CODE B | 6 | 10 | 0.6 |
| CODE A | 4 | 10 | 0.4 |
| CODE C | 9 | 10 | 0.9 |
| CODE D | 0 | 10 | 0 |

and so on for whichever error codes show up

I'd Like for the output to be:

| CODE | Numerator | Denominator | Error Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Type 1 | 15 | 10 | 1.5 |
| Type 2 | 4 | 10 | 0.4 |
| Type 4 | 0 | 10 | 0 |

and so on for appropriate groupings.

How do I go about doing this?

I've used dictionaries and I've used `isin()` with a list of types to no avail.

Here's a less simplified version of my example files:

| CODE | Power Cycle | Panics | Temp | App Restart |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Panic |  | X |  |  |
| Power Reset-Power_Reset-Hard Power | X |  |  |  |
| Power Reset-Hard_Power-Hard Power | X |  |  |  |
| HARD-App-Restart |  |  |  | X |
| Code-Reason Temperature |  |  | X |  |

and so on for 10 columns and 57 rows

| CODE | Numerator | Denominator | Error Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Power Reset-Power_Reset-Hard Power | 6 | 10 | 0.6 |
| Panic | 4 | 10 | 0.4 |
| Power Reset-Hard_Power-Hard Power | 9 | 10 | 0.9 |
| HARD-App-Restart | 0 | 10 | 0 |

and so on for as many rows for whichever error codes show up

Desired output:
|CODE|Numerator|Denominator|Error Rate|
|----|---------|-----------|----------|
|Power Cycle|  15   |  10       | 1.5      |
|Panic|   4   | 10        |  0.4     |
|App Restart |  0   |  10       |  0       |

Answer (score 0):

Say first dataframe df1 second df2

```
#convert Code to CODE in first dataframe with str.upper for standardization
df1.CODE = df1.CODE.str.upper()

#replace X with column names and remove nan values
df1["new"] = df1.filter(like="T").replace("X", pd.Series(df1.columns, df1.columns)).stack().to_numpy()

#replace CODE A,B,C,D,E with Type 1,2,3,4
df2["CODE"] = df2[["CODE"]].replace(df1[["CODE","new"]].set_index("CODE").to_dict()["new"],regex=True)
```

df2

```
    CODE    Numerator   Denominator Error Rate
0   Type 1      6          10         0.6
1   Type 2      4          10         0.4
2   Type 1      9          10         0.9
3   Type 4      0          10         0.0
```

Comment: Thank you, from there I'd just be able to do a ```groupby()``` to merge the codes of similar types together?

Comment: Wanna use groupby ? In here  `groupby` isn't needed It depends on your question. Did my code work ? Is there a point I missed ?

Comment: I haven't gotten it to work. My dataframes are more robust than the examples I included, so I'm trying to adjust for that fact. I also want to make sure to combine occurrences of the same error type. Like how Code B and Code C are the same type, to not just convert them into type, but to add their numerators together.

In real life Code B is something like "Power Reset-Power_Reset-Hard Power" and Code C is something like "Power Reset-Hard_Power-Hard Power"

Comment: When I apply your code to my data and adjust for correct names, I get a value error: ```ValueError: Length of values (35) does not match length of index (56)```